# What the HTTP specification says about HTTP requests on a plain text without header

Tags: http-headers, server-side-scripting

Some times in small shell scripts, I use an http request on a raw text file with no header, only a uuid string for identification. For example, in the apache document root, I might have a file 
`uuid.html` that contains only the uuid string `2c465f47-a734-43a0-98ab-13a2b574ccaa`, no header, nothing else. When I do an hhtp request on this file, say via `content=$(wget somedomain/uuid.html -o /dev/null -q -O -)`, where `somedomain` resolve to my server, as expected `$content` is set to the uuid string. I do this to make sure that somedomain is really resolving to my server. There might be a better way to accomplish the same goal, but that is not my question. The question is whether this is the expected behavior in accordance to HTTP specification? I mean, perhaps, this behavior is not a part of the HTTP specification and, in some other server, `$content` will  not be the uuid string, some extra header might be automatically added. I know, I could go and read the specification myself, but I feel it is such a simple question that one should not have to go back to the original, lengthy and verbose specification to figure out the answer.

Comment: Why would you expect that request and response not to have any headers?   Wget is a fairly advanced tool and it handles all the headers for you.   Unless you use the `--save-headers` command line flag, it wouldn't show them to you at all, even though it uses them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be explicitly setting HTTP headers but wget certainly will be.

If you run the same command with the `-d` (debug) flag you'll see more verbose output including the request and response headers:

```
$ wget -d https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/robots.txt
[...]
---request begin---
GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.20.1 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: webmasters.stackexchange.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
[...]
```

Comment: If you add that wget also manages the response header, which is what the question was about, then I will accept it. BTW, I realized soon after having asked my question that it showed that I did not know the HTTP protocol. Of course, there is always an header in the HTTP response.  It's wget that strips the header. I knew these things, but they were just not lively in my mind. I feel ashamed.